# Adding Google Maps with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, google-maps, qgis-3

In QGIS 2.18.16 I'm using the following code (and it works).

```
import requests
service_url = "https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}"
service_uri = "type=xyz&zmin=0&zmax=21&url="+requests.utils.quote(service_url)
tms_layer = iface.addRasterLayer(service_uri, "Google Sat", "wms")
```

How should I modify it to work in the QGIS 2.99?

Answer (score 6):

Here is the answer: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18078. 
Thank you @ndawson for help. This code works in QGIS3:

```
import requests
service_url = "mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}" 
service_uri = "type=xyz&zmin=0&zmax=21&url=https://"+requests.utils.quote(service_url)
tms_layer = iface.addRasterLayer(service_uri, "Google Sat", "wms")
#lyrs=y - hybrid
#lyrs=s - sat
#lyrs=m - road map
```